# AlarmManager not calling service in the given time interval

Tags: android, android-activity, service, alarmmanager

In my project i am calling service continuously after every 30 seconds and it was working fine but now its calling service in every 60 seconds even If i change time interval (from 30 seconds to 5 seconds or whatever). this is my code

```
 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
  Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Myservice.class);
        PendingIntent pendingintetnt= PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, intent , 0);
        sendBroadcast(pendingintetnt);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
       alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),timeinterval, pendingintetnt);
```

I tried all this option also but still it is not working

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), timeinterval, pendingintetnt);
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis()+2000,timeinterval, pendingintetnt);
```

I am surprised why it is not working for given time interval why it is taking fix time 60 seconds every time.

Comment: have you define service in menifest?

Comment: have you registered receiver in your manifest?  <receiver android:name=".alarmreceiver.Alarmreceiver" >
        </receiver> like this

Comment: Well first off-  Android won't do any alarm for less than 10s (I believe, it may be 20s).  Below that you'll either be rounded up or ignored.  Use a Handler instead.  Above that-  android does NOT promise exact wakeup times unless you jump through hoops.  It does inexact timers to save battery power.  The correct way to do an actual exact timer depends on the version of Android you're using.  They keep changing it to force people to inexact timers.

Comment: @JinalPatel -Please read the question correctly.Everything is defined already correct code is working fine but it just not working as i want.

Comment: @Bhoomi-Please read the question correctly.Everything is defined already correct. code is working fine but it just not working as i want.

Comment: @GabeSechan- I am also talking about 30 seconds but still it is not working. And second thing i can't use handler because i am calling service even when app is closed. And what do you mean by your later comment its not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From android 5.1 minimum value you can set is 60 seconds. If you set minimum value less than 60 then android forced value and register alarm for 60 seconds only and call service in every 60 seconds.